# virsh restore with modified xml "Error: xml modification unsupported"

Tags: xen, libvirt, virsh

I'm trying to restore an a Xen VM (domain) from state file which I create previously. At the restore I need to modify the XML of this VM with the following command:

```
virsh restore domU.state --xml newconfig.xml
```

This command triggers an error with the following text:

```
error: Failed to restore domain from domU.state
error: argument unsupported: xml modification unsupported
```

What I already try:

1. restore without XML, which works perfectly.
2. run the command with the original xml the domain was created from
3. run the command with a totally different file which is not even an XML

At step 2. & 3. the error output was always the same.

Used versions:
xen 4.11.1
libvirt 5.1.0
os fedora 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests, the ability to pass in custom XML when restoring a guest from a snapshot, is unfortunately not supported by the libvirt Xen (libxl) driver. This feature only works with QEMU/KVM at this time.

Comment: thanks for your hint, I found out that we use an own patch for this in a previous version. Now we try to add this feature to upstream.